# Objective C: Return an array from a class method

Tags: objective-c

I have a NSMutablearray property in my class and i need to access it from another class what should i do ?? i tried to  access it using a class method called breakfast , but it didnt see the  property !!

This is my code

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController { 
    NSMutableArray *food;
}

+ (NSArray*)breakfast;

@property (nonatomic , strong) NSMutableArray * food;
```

// in .m file

```
+ (NSMutableArray*)breakfast {
    return self.food ; // here class method dont see the property called food
}
```

Comment: You need to clarify your goal. Why do you need a class method? A class method does not work on any one instance.

Comment: Please clarify WHY are you trying to do - what's a big point for what you're doing - also read my answer for suggestion in case of I maybe guessed what are trying to do here.

Comment: i need to khnow why i cant see any of class property inside the class method ?

Comment: You can't access 'self' from a class method, as it doesn't exist.

Comment: ok thank u :)  ,, i will find another way to access data from another controller

Comment: You can access the `food` property from other classes. You just need to have a reference to an actual instance of the `FirstViewController` to do so. There is no need for a class method in such a case.

Comment: but then it will be emty , i need to define astatic property

Comment: There is no such thing as a static property. And how would it be empty? If you have an instance of your view controller you can both set and get the `food` property value.

Comment: but i will put the property values in my controller , and read it from another one , when i create an instance every thing will be nil at begin , and i need to set it value in its contoller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
// FirstViewController.h
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
}

+(NSMutableArray*) breakfast;

// FirstViewController.m
+(NSMutableArray*) breakfast
{
  static NSMutableArray* _breakfast = nil;

  if (_breakfast == nil)
  {
    // _breakfast alloc init
  }

  return _breakfast;
}
```

Comment: the breakfast array implemented outside the class method , i connect to server and get data from it and put these data in the food property , i need to access that data from another class so im trying to build a class method , here you want me to alloc and init the breakfast array inside the class method

Comment: This variable (_breakfast) will be allocated just once, first time you will be accessing this method.

Comment: I don't know what you trying to do. You can access it from another class like this: [[FirstViewController breakfast] addObject:@"object"];
    NSString *str = [FirstViewController breakfast][0];

Answer (score -1):

Biggest issue is that you cannot use "self.propertyname" inside static (+) methods. You need to have an instance of class to call self.

Other problem is that you have "Food" and "food" - different case in @property and getter you are trying to use - they are case-sensitive.
Also you have NSArray and NSMutableArray in .m and .h file.
On top of that - you don't really need this local variable declaration.

I think you described your problem in wrong way. If you want to pass data between your view controllers, check: [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

If you want to have data available for applicataion in general - create singleton.

Comment: So how does this answer the question?  The OP wants to access data via a class method.

Comment: You can't reference an instance property in a class method. You've just repeated the problem in the OP's original code.

Comment: How are you calling it ?

Comment: you can absolutely use self in class methods, it means this class object.

Comment: @GradyPlayer buy not self.property :D

Comment: yeah true enough, removing my down vote, which was really for your crappy comments on @trojanfoe's answer.

Comment: thank u , I didn't khnow that i cant call self in a class method , so l changed the code and i passed data in another way and its worked :)